Packaging an Android game in Unreal 5, "Max memory exceeded, goes to garbage collection, all the cooking restarts again, runs in a loop"
The packaging keeps on cooking forever in a loop, it reaches for about 1500 packages remain to cook and then get "max memory exceeded" and then "says garbage collection was not successful" and proceeds to cook all the  packages again from the beginning and runs in a loop.
I've also tried packaging the game in ASTC but same issue, after a while of cooking, i start to get warnings like, Failed to create directory for these and these assets and keeps on giving me the same warnings in a loop and never ends.
I'm thinking that my game is too heavy because it has a lot of polygons.
I've tried to remove all heavy assets in the game, just to see if the packaging errors is occurring due to heavy assets, still facing the same issues.
error Screen Shot
